# Integrate share iOS / whatsapp in my app. Share Picture and text at the same time to whatsapp

Tags: ios, image, text, share, whatsapp

Is there already a way to share the picture and the text from my app to whatsapp in one motion?

I can only find a android solution. It must be possible with iOS? Hope anybody has got the solution!

I found the solution for both picture and text over here, but Im looking for the option which android yet provides; from my app, in one motion, send a picture and text to a whatsapp contact.

Help is very much needed, tried everything and searched everywhere! Will the expert please stand up :)! Thanks in advance, hope to hear from you!

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp has a "Custom URL Scheme" and "Document Interaction" (http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013).

But it looks like it does not support annotions for setting the text like Instagram (http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

This is the way to share but WITHOUT text.

```
self.documentationInteractionController =[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:jpegFileURL];
self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;

self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"public.jpeg";
self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";

// NOT WORKING - Found this solution, no success
self.documentationInteractionController.annotation = @{@"message":@"Text here",@"text":@"Text here"};

// NOT WORKING - Found other solution, no success
self.documentationInteractionController.annotation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text=Text here"];

// WORKING - BUT only for instagram
self.documentationInteractionController.annotation = @{@"InstagramCaption":@"Text here"};

[self.documentationInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Hope someone has the complete answer to the question, i am also stuck with the image and text combo.